# AngularJS - calling methods on the parent scope from isolated scope directive not passing arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I'm just learning angular and creating some simple directives to try some things.  I am having (what I think) is a small problem attempting to pass parameters from the directive to a controller function on the root scope.

Please see the following jsfiddle and note that I clicking the button (from within the directive) gives me undefined whereas it seems to work fine if clicking the button from the controller itself.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue1trkt9/)

Am I just missing something syntax wise?  Or am I completely wrong in how this should work?  I have made several attempts at placing variables in different locations (note the 'xxx') in the fiddle to see if anything would work and I get either errors or nothing.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

   <!-- root scope -->
   <div style="background-color: teal">
       <button ng-click="propertyF('yyy')" >F</button>
   </div>

   <!-- directive firing methods on the root scope -->
   <div style="background-color: coral">
       <my-directive3 property6="propertyF()"></my-directive3>
   </div>

</div>


var app = angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.propertyF = function (aValue) {
            alert("propertyF fired: '" + aValue + "'");
        };
    }
])
.directive('myDirective3', function() {
    var directive = {
        link : function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("link directive 3");
        },
        restrict : 'EA',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            property6: '&'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="property6(\'xxx\')">property6</button>'
    };
    return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way Angular works, are you passing a function binding and specifying arguments.  `propertyF()` does not specify any arguments.

```
property6="propertyF(arg)"
```

Then you can do Angular's unique syntax for handling this:

```
ng-click="property6({arg:\'xxx\'})"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ue1trkt9/1/